# Eu gostaria de saber como adicionar div html através do js puro

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso adicionar varias novas `div`s na `div` `id "new-list-container"` clicando no botão de `id "button"`.

No código JavaScript que eu criei, quando eu clico, cria apenas uma `div` e se clicar denovo não cria outra.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/css/style.css">
    <title>To do list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1>To do List</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="create-list">
            <input type="text" name="list-title" maxlength="30"> 
            <button id="button" class="btn" onclick="newList()">Criar nova lista</button>
         </div>

         <div id="new-list-container">
            
         </div>

         <div class="remove-all-list">

             <div>

                <input type="checkbox" name="remove" id="remove">
                <label for="remove">Deseja remover todas as listas?</label>

                <button class="btn">Remover listas</button>

            </div>   

         </div>
    </main>

    <footer>

    </footer>

    <script src="style/js/code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ps: É a primeira vez que posto aqui então não sei usar muito bem a plataforma.

Comment: qual o código javascript que cria a div?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode criar por meio do createElement()

Segue um exemplo

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
```

após criar a div, caso queira colocar um texto você utilizará o .innerHTML ou .innerText, depende a finalidade de tal.

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.innerHTML = "<b>Hello World!</b>";
```

para aparecer na página você precisará utilizar o body.appendChild()

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.innerHTML = "<b>Hello World!</b>";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Para saber mais sobre o createElement() [Clique aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

Comment: Obrigado, estou começando agora no js e seu comentário me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

Lhe faltou um pouco de empenho e pesquisa, numa pesquisa rapida do google você [tem esse exemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [este exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840326/how-can-i-create-and-style-a-div-using-javascript) [e também este exemplo.](https://www.techiedelight.com/dynamically-create-div-javascript/)

Antes de fazeres alguma pergunta no StackOverflow sempre faça uma pesquisa detalhada para teres certeza que não irás publicar uma pergunta duplicada e teres downvotes desnecessários.

Answer (score -2):

Poste seu código javascript, assim podemos ver o que você fez e assim ajudar.

A lógica do funcionamento é assim, você precisa fazer um append a cada vez que for inserir, do contrário você só reescreve a div.

Mas essencialmente uma função que adicione novas divs (diretamente no DOM) seria algo assim:

```
function addDiv() {
 let newDiv = document.createElement("div"), //Cria um element DIV
 container = document.getElementById("new-list-container"); //Grava a sua div que receberá novos dados em uma variável

 newDiv.innerHTML = '<p>Novo conteúdo</p>'; //Insere um conteúdo dentro da nova div

 container.append(newDiv); //Adiciona ao final da sua div o novo conteúdo
 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta graças a ela consegui resolver o problema. Eu não estava colocando o append então so estava reescrevendo a div.

Answer (score -2):

é bem simples, podemos fazer usando document.createElement()

```
<div id="meuDiv"></div>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var div = document.createElement("DIV");//crio uma variável para definir que o elemento será uma div
        div.innerHTML = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";//crio uma tag H1(com "hello world" escrito nela) dentro da div
        document.getElementById("meuDiv").appendChild(div);//pego o nome da div pai usando seu id("meuDiv") depois uso appendChild para criar um elemento filho dentro da div
    }
   myFunction();//chamo a função para criar a div
</script>
```

você também poderia usar o body como pai apenas trocando `document.getElementById("meuDiv")` por `document.body` ou você também pode colocar o elemento pai em uma variável:

```
var pai = document.getElementById("meuDiv"); 
//ou apenas
var pai = document.body;//caso queira que o pai fosse o body
pai.appendChild(div);
```